# Unable to install ts-jest: npm ERR! code E404

Tags: node.js, typescript, unit-testing, npm, jestjs

I am trying to install ts-jest in my react typescript project:

> npm install --save-dev ts-jest

But, I keep getting this error:

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'diff-sequences@29.6.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: '@jest/schemas@29.6.3',
npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '^14.15.0 || ^16.10.0 || >=18.0.0' },
npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v15.8.0', npm: '7.5.1' }
npm WARN EBADENGINE }
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/pure-rand/-/pure-rand-6.0.4.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'pure-rand@https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/pure-rand/-/pure-rand-6.0.4.tgz' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2023-10-30T09_50_09_140Z-debug.log
```

Noticing the warnings, I tried updating node to 16.10.0:
I no longer get the warning, but I still get the 404 error:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/pure-rand/-/pure-rand-6.0.4.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  'pure-rand@https://packagecloud.io/github/git-lfs/npm/pure-rand/-/pure-rand-6.0.4.tgz' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ahmed/.npm/_logs/2023-10-30T09_52_25_622Z-debug.log
```

The problem is the rest of the packages get installed properly. So I'm not really sure what's going on here.

Comment: Try to upgrade your **node** version. Probably it is unsupperted. You can check your node version by `node -v`